# How does $\frac{t^2}{t+1}$ equal $t-1+\frac{1}{t+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I do the long division:

1: t+1 goes into $t^2$ t times

2: Subtract $t^2$ + 1 from $t^2$ and get -1

3: Answer:  t - $\frac{1}{t+1}$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your answer can't be right. Plug in t=0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In step 2 you should be subtracting $t^2+t$, not $t^2+1$.

Answer (score 7):

$\dfrac{t^2}{t+1}=\dfrac{t^2-1+1}{t+1}=\dfrac{t^2-1}{t+1}+\dfrac{1}{t+1}=\dfrac{(t-1)(t+1)}{t+1}+\dfrac{1}{t+1}=t-1+\dfrac{1}{t+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial division will also give you the answer quickly:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
     &   &    & t   & &  -1  &  & \\
(t+1)& | &    & t^2 & &  +0t &  &+0  \\
     &   & -( & t^2 & &  +t  &) &     \\
     &   &    &     & & -t   &  & +0 \\
     &   &    &     &-(&-t   & -1 & )\\
     &   &    &     &  &     & +1\\
\end{array}$$

$$\textrm{Result : } \boxed{t- 1 + \dfrac{1}{t+ 1}}.$$